# How to get all properties that are anotated with some attribute?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am just starting with Roslyn, and I want to find all properties that are annotated with attribute names "OneToOne". I fired up SyntaxVisualizer and was able to get reference to that node, but I am wondering is there a simpler way to achieve this. This is what I have:

```
var prop = document.GetSyntaxRoot()
             .DescendantNodes()
             .OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
             .Where(p => p.DescendantNodes()
                 .OfType<AttributeSyntax>()
                 .Any(a => a.DescendantNodes()
                     .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
                     .Any(i => i.DescendantTokens()
                         .Any(dt => dt.Kind == SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken
                                 && dt.ValueText == "OneToOne"))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I would go about this using Semantics, not Syntax.  Something like (off the top of my head):

```
var attributeSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("ConsoleApplication1.OneToOneAttribute");
var propertySymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("ConsoleApplication1.Program")
                     .GetMembers()
                     .Where(m => 
                            m.Kind == CommonSymbolKind.Property && 
                            m.GetAttributes().Any(a => a.AttributeClass.MetadataName == attributeSymbol.MetadataName));
```

Comment: I could not get it using exact syntax, I've had to change last line to  following: && m.GetAttributes().Any(a => a.AttributeClass.MetadataName == attSymbol.MetadataName));

Comment: :Seems like when one gets "classSymbol" it cannot be cast to "SourcePropertySymbol" to get the type of the property? Do we from here walk the syntax nodes to find the type? I had to do following to get the type name of the property  member.DeclaringSyntaxNodes.First().ChildNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().First().GetFirstToken().Value;

Comment: Well, "SourcePropertySymbol" is an internal type, but you should be able cast to the public "PropertySymbol" type and get the "Type" of the property that way.

Comment: Can you get the containing type's name (e.g. ConsoleApplication1.Program) when writing an analyzer?

Answer (score 3):

My approach for similar task (I wanted to rewrite methods and properties decorated with specific attribute) was to find all usages of the attribute symbol and then iterate over references and get method/property declaration syntax:

```
var attributeSymbol = compilation.FindSymbol(typeof(<Your attribute type>));
var references = attributeSymbol.FindReferences(solution);

foreach (ReferencedSymbol referencedSymbol in references)
{
    foreach (ReferenceLocation location in referencedSymbol.Locations)
    {
        var propertyDeclaration = location.Document.GetSyntaxRoot()
            .FindToken(location.Location.SourceSpan.Start)
            .Parent
            .FirstAncestorOrSelf<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
    }
}
```

I had to write few extension methods to make life easier:

```
public static class CompilationExtensions
{
    public static INamedTypeSymbol FindSymbol(this CommonCompilation compilation, Type searchedType)
    {
        var splitFullName = searchedType.FullName.Split('.');
        var namespaceNames = splitFullName.Take(splitFullName.Length - 1).ToArray();
        var className = splitFullName.Last();

        if (namespaceNames.Length == 0)
            return compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetAllTypes(new CancellationToken()).First(n => n.Name == className);

        var namespaces = compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers();
        INamespaceSymbol namespaceContainingType = null;
        foreach (var name in namespaceNames)
        {
            namespaceContainingType = namespaces.First(n => n.Name == name);
            namespaces = namespaceContainingType.GetNamespaceMembers();
        }

        return namespaceContainingType.GetAllTypes(new CancellationToken()).First(n => n.Name == className);
    }
}

public static class INamespaceSymbolExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(this INamespaceSymbol @namespace, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Queue<INamespaceOrTypeSymbol> symbols = new Queue<INamespaceOrTypeSymbol>();
        symbols.Enqueue(@namespace);

        while (symbols.Count > 0)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            INamespaceOrTypeSymbol namespaceOrTypeSymbol = symbols.Dequeue();
            INamespaceSymbol namespaceSymbol = namespaceOrTypeSymbol as INamespaceSymbol;
            if (namespaceSymbol == null)
            {
                INamedTypeSymbol typeSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol) namespaceOrTypeSymbol;
                Array.ForEach(typeSymbol.GetTypeMembers().ToArray(), symbols.Enqueue);

                yield return typeSymbol;
            }
            else
            {
                Array.ForEach(namespaceSymbol.GetMembers().ToArray(), symbols.Enqueue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no FindSymbol on compilation?

Comment: @epitka oops, totally forgot that `FindSymbol` was extension method. Added code to the answer.

Comment: Is GetAllTypes also extension method on GlobalNamespace?

Answer (score 1):

This is my helper class that finds all properties, class name and class namespace

```
public class CsharpClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public List<CsharpProperty> Properties { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryKeyType { get; set; }

    public class CsharpProperty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public CsharpProperty(string name, string type)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
        }
    }

    public CsharpClass()
    {
        Properties = new List<CsharpProperty>();
    }
}

public static class CsharpClassParser
{
    public static CsharpClass Parse(string content)
    {
        var cls = new CsharpClass();
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(content);
        var members = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            if (member is PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
            {
                cls.Properties.Add(new CsharpClass.CsharpProperty(
                     property.Identifier.ValueText,
                     property.Type.ToString())
                 );
            }

            if (member is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclaration)
            {
                cls.Namespace = namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString();
            }

            if (member is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
            {
                cls.Name = classDeclaration.Identifier.ValueText;

                cls.PrimaryKeyType = FindPrimaryKeyType(classDeclaration);
            }

            //if (member is MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Method: " + method.Identifier.ValueText);
            //}
        }


        return cls;
    }

    private static string FindPrimaryKeyType(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
    {
        if (classDeclaration == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (classDeclaration.BaseList == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var baseClass in classDeclaration.BaseList.Types)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(baseClass.Type.ToString(), @"<(.*?)>");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var primaryKey = match.Groups[1].Value;

                if (AppConsts.PrimaryKeyTypes.Any(x => x.Value == primaryKey))
                {
                    return primaryKey;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
const string content = @"
namespace Acme.Airlines.AirCraft
{
    public class AirCraft
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual int Code { get; set; }

        public AirCraft()
        {

        }
    }
}";

var csharpClass = CsharpClassParser.Parse(content);

Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Name);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Namespace);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Properties.Count);
```

Comment: good answer, but i need the "AppConsts.PrimaryKeyTypes" collection,please provide it?